# Making multidimensional lists in python

Tags: python, list

This question maybe asked earlier (atleast topic wise) , but still I couldn't find a solution for my specific problem. Basically, I need a multidimensional array in python. Such that:

I will be able to access contents in list by :

```
contenets[no_of_record][record].
```

So I have a file like :

```
101, Mrs. Jones' Math Class, 10100000001, Jones, Barbara, , , , 10100000011, Gutierrez, Kimberly, 2
101, Mrs. Jones' Math Class, 10100000001, Jones, Barbara, , , , 10100000013, Mercado, Toby, 1
101, Mrs. Jones' Math Class, 10100000001, Jones, Barbara, , , , 10100000014, Garcia, Lizzie, 1
101, Mrs. Jones' Math Class, 10100000001, Jones, Barbara, , , , 10100000015, Cruz, Alex, 1
```

Now I have to maintain a multi dimensional array where no_of_record points to row number and the record will be the column number.

I want something similar to this:

```
contents=[][]

for lines in source_file:
                contents[no_of_records][]=lines.rstrip().split(',')
                print contents[no_of_records]
                no_of_records+=1
```

I am sure the snippet above is syntactically wrong, I am just trying to give an idea of what im searching for. Thanks for your help.

-Sethu

Comment: i'd suggest [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it with `dicts`, which may be better, if you want to use something other than numbers for the indices.

```
contents = []
tmp_rcd = {'classnum': 101, 'classname': "Mrs. Jones' Math Class", ...}
contents.append.tmp.rcd
...
print contents[i]['classname']
```

Comment: Dictionary sounds perfect. I just have to find out how to use it. I have never used them before.

Comment: If you want to combine this with `csv`, there's `csv.DictReader`, which can take the field names from the first row, or you can specify them yourself.

Answer (score 4):

from the csv examples of the doc you should do something along the lines

```
import csv
rows = []
with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
        rows.append(row)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want a list of lists you can do it with this:

```
contents = [l.split(',') for l in fh] # fh is a file handle here.
```

There's no good reason not to use the `csv` module if you're actually working with a csv file though.

Comment: It is a csv file. Im surprised I didnt search for an inbuilt csv library. Thanks for mentioning it !!

Answer (score 1):

Use a single `list`, but populate it further using `list` objects.

```
contents = []
for i, line in enumerate(source_file):
    contents.append(line.rstrip().split(','))
    print contents[i]
```

It looks like you're parsing a csv file, though. I'd suggest using the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module in stead.

Comment: You can't assign to an index that doesn't exist in a list.  It raises IndexError.

Comment: @g.d.d.c Realized that after I read over my answer again. Edited.